# Cloning an array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I am having the following array of objects in a react app:

```
const ar = [{name:'name', age: 20}];
```

how can I multiply the ar array of objects so it has the same structure, and create like a 1000 copy of it? example:

```
const ar = [{name:'nameOne', age: 21},{name:'nameTwo', age: 22}]
```

and so on

Comment: Do you want a copy of the object or just the same keys but with different values?

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be different, you should do that with a for loop and Array.push(), like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
    ar.push({name: "name" + i, age: i + 1});
}
```

Making it be "one, two, three" will be quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

For the shallow copy you can use the new es6 spread operator for arrays.

```
let arr_to_copy = [{name:'name', age: 20}];

let output_arr = [];

let i = 1000;

while (i > 0) {

  output_arr.push([...arr_to_copy])

  i--;
}

console.log(output_arr)
```

This won't work for deep (nested) data. Here is a good post on the [spread operator](https://medium.com/@kevinlai76/the-spread-operator-deep-and-shallow-copies-d193ac9b58bf)

For nested data, you will have to use a lib like `lodash`, or make your own function.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ar = [{
  name: 'nameOne',
  age: 21
}]
```

You Can use below for Loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  ar.push({
    'name': 'name' + i,
    'age': 21 + i
  });
}
```

Comment: You can `push` and `splice` an array declared with `const`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code to clone the array 1000 times:

```js
const ar = [{name:'name', age: 20}];

var i = 0;
var newArray = [];

while(i < 1000){
  newArray.push(ar[0]);
  i++;
}

console.log(newArray.length, newArray[999])
```